# Transactionscope not working on SQLite in Subsonic

Tags: vb.net, subsonic

I have trouble using the transactionscope on SQLite, i am using the following code. Changes are still commited to the database while i don't call the ts.Complete() function.

```
Using ts As New System.Transactions.TransactionScope()  
  Using sharedConnectionScope As New SubSonic.SharedDbConnectionScope()
  ' Do your individual saves here' 
  If all OK      
    ts.Complete()   
  End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly, you're going to need to call BeginTransaction and EndTransaction somewhere in there to tell SQLite that you're entering and subsequently leaving a transaction block--if I recall correctly, wrapping a (using transaction As IDbCommand.BeginTransaction ()) around any transaction-based code is necessary (though I haven't done ADO.NET in a while).

Comment: No, not necessary if you're using a TransactionScope like this.

Comment: It does work though, but i still think the previous method should work on subsonic.

I don't know if it is an bug in subsonic or in the SQLite ado.net profider

Comment: most probably it is SQLite ADO.net Provider

Comment: Yeah, I looked up TransactionScope this morning and saw that technically, you don't need to BeginTransaction/EndTransaction specifically. +1 for it being a bug in the ADO.NET provider.

Comment: Could you post the code you ended up using as the solution? ie using BeginTransaction/EndTransaction